# How to insert col-md-12 inside col-md-2 and take full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had inserted a  row (col-md-12) div inside col-md-2 div. I want row div to take the full width of the page. But it takes only the width of the parent col-md-2. How can I overcome this issue in the bootstrap way?

```
  <div class="options-main row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">       
           <img src="#" class="img-responsive">        
        <div class="options-main-sub row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 border-box">

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
This is how it looks in actual. Each column in the first row will have 6 corresponding columns in second row

Comment: Your question and your code does not match.

Comment: If you want to utilise full width, then why do you use class `col-md-2`?

Comment: @niyasc actually parent col-md-2 is one out of six col-md-2 in its parent row

Comment: Then how can you expect it to take full width?

Comment: Please add a layout that you want to create. That will help to understand things in better way.

Comment: @niyasc added an image to eplain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate `row` elements for each row that you want to create in your page. This is a basic concept in bootstrap and you should not be going ahead without understanding this concept.

Your problem can be solved as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-2">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note, in above to code snippet, I have replaced `col-md-x` with `col-xs-x` to see same preview on small screens.

Also note the `col-xs-push-x` class. It is used to set offset. So, in this demo I assume that corresponding to an entry in second column of first row, there are 6 columns in second row.

You need to use some `class` or `id` relation to indicate that, a particular second row belongs an entry in first row.

---

Alternatively, you can enclose second row inside a `fixed` block

```css
.hover {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-2">
      Content
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, please note that this **not** a bootstrap way.